# retrieve data from firebase realtime database orderby

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

i have this data base : [database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnYXJ.png)

im using this code to retrieve the posts list:

```
 public async Task<List<PostItem>> GetUserPostsList()
        {

            return (await App.FirebaseService.fbClient.Child("Users/" + Settings.LastUserID + "/Posts").OnceAsync<PostItem>()).Select((item) =>
            new PostItem
            {
                TimePosted = item.Object.TimePosted,
                PostText = item.Object.PostText
            }).ToList();

        }
```

i want to get the posts ordered by TimePosted (from new to old)

how do i use the orderby function and how do i set the rules in the realtime database

i've read this docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

but didnt understand how to make it in my case

Comment: You can add the rule like this sceenshot(For testing, I order it by the Phone).https://imgur.com/a/9TW9Je6, then you get the value by `firebase.Child("User").OrderByValue();`

Comment: But in my case the TimePosted property is under the patch users/posts. It should still work?